# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

During the compilation of the JSP template I get the following exception:

> getFriendImage() is not a method

I have tried rebuilding the class, but no results. The item inside the src is a link to an image that works fine.

```
package classes;

public class Friends {

  private String username;
  private String friendname;
  private String complete;
  private String datestring;
  private String user_image;
  private String friendImage;
  private String online;

  public Friends(String username, String friendname, String complete, 
                 String datestring, String user_image, 
                 String friendImage, String online) {
    this.username = username;
    this.friendname = friendname;
    this.complete = complete;
    this.datestring = datestring;
    this.user_image = user_image;
    this.friendImage = friendImage;
    this.online = online;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getFriendname() {
    return friendname;
  }

  public void setFriendname(String friendname) {
    this.friendname = friendname;
  }

  public String getComplete() {
    return complete;
  }

  public void setComplete(String complete) {
    this.complete = complete;
  }

  public String getDatestring() {
    return datestring;
  }

  public void setDatestring(String datestring) {
    this.datestring = datestring;
  }

  public String getUser_image() {
    return user_image;
  }

  public void setUser_image(String user_image) {
    this.user_image = user_image;
  }

  public String getFriendImage() {
    return friendImage;
  }

  public void setFriendImage(String friendImage) {
    this.friendImage = friendImage;
  }

  public String getOnline() {
    return online;
  }

  public void setOnline(String online) {
    this.online = online;
  }
}

 session.setAttribute("friendsList", friendsList);
```

The JSP template

```
<ul id="friends_list">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${friendsList}">
        <li class="friend_item"><img class="friend_list_image" 
            src="${friendsList.getFriendImage()}"  
            alt="friend_image"/>
            <label>${friendsList.getFriendname()}</label>
            <img class="message_icon" src="Images/Message.png" 
                 alt="Message_Icon" title="Message" onclick="message_friend()"/>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not normally supposed to access those methods like that. Usually what you should do is just use the field names you have declared in your Friends class to access them, providing you have set these variables beforehand.

Also if you provide `var="item"` in your `<c:forEach` then you should access them with `${item.somefieldname}`

```
<ul id="friends_list">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${friendsList}">
        <li class="friend_item">
         <img class="friend_list_image" src="${item.friendImage}" alt="friend_image"/>
         <label>${item.friendname}</label>
         <img class="message_icon" src="Images/Message.png" alt="Message_Icon" title="Message" onclick="message_friend()"/>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Also note the capitalization:

```
  private String username;
  private String friendname;
  private String complete;
  private String datestring;
  private String user_image;
  private String friendImage; //capitalized here, be careful!
  private String online;
```

Comment: no problem, honest mistake. Feel free to mark as correct answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to access the `getFriendImage()` on the `Friend` item and not on the whole list. If so, you should access it like this

```
src="${item.getFriendImage()}"
```

The same applies to the `label` which should be

```
<label>${item.getFriendname()}</label>
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't call the class `Friends`, in plural. Constructing a new (single) *friend* with `new Friends()` is quite misleading, so the singular `Friend` is fine.